# Modifying 3d Model on server

Tags: laravel, model, 3d, lumen, babylonjs

I'm developing a tool where the user can create a custom texture for each mesh of a 3d model ( for example: 3d model is a house (.glb) and the user can create for each wall a custom texture). On the client side I'm using HTML5, React and on the server side there is Laravel / Lumen.

The part for creating the textures is done and at the end I have .PNG images lying on the Server. Furthermore I already have created a 3d preview with Babylonjs. For the preview I Import the 3d model form the Server and add the custom textures with Babylonjs to my 3d model. The whole Thing works fine.

Now I would like to avoid the extra client-server-communication ( import 3d model, import each texture ). My idea was to add the textures to the 3d model on the Server and Import only the model with the textures within. Unfortunately I could not find anything for Laravel/ Lumen. Is there anything for Laravel / Lumen to modify my 3d model and add the created textures to it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you'll find anything that specific packaged for direct use with Laravel, and you might not find any for use with PHP for that matter (though I may be mistaken). Instead I suggest you should be searching for *any* tool you can use on the server to apply texture to models, and just execute any commands for that tool from your PHP backend to get a processed file you can then serve to your client app.